# jQuery Countdown error: returning NaN

Tags: jquery, countdown

I'm using this jQuery countdown plugin: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

I'm trying this to set the countdown date:

```
var countdownValue = $('#countdown-value').text();
alert(countdownValue);
var newYear = new Date(countdownValue); 
$('#countdown-l').countdown({until: newYear});
```

Div to set value:

```
<div id="countdown-value" style="display:none">2011, 07-1, 13</div>
```

The alert is returning '2011, 07-1, 13'.

That's what I have entered in the db, so that's correct. But the countdown is returning `NaN` for each number. However, if I directly enter `2011, 07-1, 13`, I get a working countdown. Are there hidden characters, or is this parsed a different way?

I'm kinda lost here.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean "directly enter?" `new Date(2011, 07-1, 13)`? or `new Date("2011, 07-1, 13")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you instantiate a `Date` object like this:

```
new Date(2011, 07-1, 13)
```

*(By the way, the `07-1` just resolves to 6, not sure if this is intended)*

You're calling the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor with the following version:

```
new Date(year, month, day)
```

This is successful, because it creates a valid date. When you call the `Date` constructor with `$('#countdown-value').text()`, you are initializing a new `Date` with the version that takes a string, essentially:

```
new Date("2011, 07-1, 13")
```

Which is not a [valid date string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

To fix this, you can either make the date you are retrieving a valid date string, or parse out the values *(Note that to make this method work easily, you'll have to change 07-1 to "6")*:

```
var countdownValue = $('#countdown-value').text();
var values = countdownValue.split(",");

alert(countdownValue);
var newYear = new Date(parseInt(values[0], 10), parseInt(values[1], 10), parseInt(values[2], 10)); 
$('#countdown-1').countdown({until: newYear });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vtFkd/

Comment: Just a side-question: does the date string have to be in that format?

Comment: @Kevin: Look at documentation for the `parse` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse, the bottom has some examples of valid date strings.

Comment: Gotcha. Is that because the `Date` method only takes dates in the format `YYYY, MM, DD`?

Comment: `Date` takes `milliseconds`, `year, month, day`, and a parameterless constructor. More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date